# DNN - RESET PASSWORD EMAIL TOKEN ERROR

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I just recently installed DNN 7.2.2 and created my own website, but unfortunately the reset password token is not working. When I try the password reset link, after entering my username, I get this message: "**Error as occur when defining the password, password has not been changed.**" Is this an issue with my site, or the DNN platform?

Environment Details:

OS: Windows server 2008 R2.

DNN versio: 7.2.2 (303).

Sql version: SQL server 2008 r2.

Event viewer shows : "Password Sent Failure".

Email template token:

```
"http://[Portal:URL]/default.aspx?ctl=PasswordReset&resetToken=[Membership:PasswordResetToken]"
```

WebConfig (authentication) :

I have already read this two tickets (they didn't resolve my problem) :

"https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-4241"

"https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-4787"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed, the problem was **PasswordResetTokenExpiration** has set to 0.

I change it to another value and it's fine now.

How to change it:
Host Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Membership Management

Comment: How did you change PasswordResetTokenExpiration?

Comment: If i still remember the PasswordResetTokenExpiration can be accessible by DNN Admin Settings or by web.config.

Host Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Membership Management

Comment: I was unable to located it in either place.  Perhaps it is labeled something slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

Get the previous DNN version (the 7.1) and copy the `website\admin\Security\PasswordReset.ascx` 
from there. There were some changes between the versions but the 7.1 was working for sure, if you still get the error then it's something with your db.